# Expanding an array within a for loop (file list)

Tags: arrays, bash, for-loop

I am running into problems when interating over files using a for-loop. For simplicity, I created a small loop which should explain which problem I have at the moment.

**Starting point:** files in a folder which have a file-specific one to three digit number at a defined position in their filename.

**Goal:** Iterate over some of these files (not all) using a for-loop.

**Problem:** I created an array containing these one to three digit numbers specific for each file. The files are called at the beginning of the for-loop and I would like to use the array to reference to the specific files. But: The array is not expanding correctly.

Hope someone can help!
(There might be several good alternative ways to do this. Maybe some of them do not need an array, but I would be interested in knowing the solution to my specific problem since I think this might be a fundamental missunderstanding in how to expand a variable as part of filenames at the beginning of a for-loop.)

This is the code:

```
declare -a SOME_SAMPLES=(37 132 253 642 242 42)

for d in prmrp_*_${SOME_SAMPLES[@]}_S*_L00?_R1_001.fastq.gz; do

    INPUT_FILE1=$(echo $d | sed 's/_L00._R1_001.fastq.gz//')
    echo ${INPUT_FILE1}

done
```

Again, this is just an example code. The problem is the `${SOME_SAMPLES[@]}` part which is not expanding correctly so the loop fails.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that in

```
prmrp_*_${SOME_SAMPLES[@]}_S*_L00?_R1_001.fastq.gz
```

it doesn't duplicate the entire expression for each element of the array, it just blindly inserts the array's elements in the middle, giving the equivalent of this:

```
prmrp_*_37 132 253 642 242 42_S*_L00?_R1_001.fastq.gz
```

... which is a bunch of separate items (`prmrp_*_37` as a wildcard expression, followed by `132` as a simple string, followed by `253` etc). AIUI you want to expand the array's contents, and then *for each element* use a wildcard expression to get all matching files. The best way to do this is to use two loops, one to expand the array, and another to find matching files:

```
for sample in "${SOME_SAMPLES[@]}"; do
    for d in prmrp_*_"${sample}"_S*_L00?_R1_001.fastq.gz; do
        ...
```

BTW, I'd also recommend using lowercase or mixed-case variable names (e.g. `sample` above) to avoid possible conflicts with the many all-caps variables with special meanings/functions. Also, I'd use a parameter expansion to remove the filename's suffix (instead of `sed`):

```
input_file1=${d%_L00?_R1_001.fastq.gz}
```

Also, you should generally put double-quotes around variable references (e.g. `echo "${input_file1}"` instead of `echo ${input_file1}`). (Assignments like `input_file1=${d...` are an exception, although double-quotes don't hurt there; they just aren't needed.) Note that in the `for` loop above, I put double-quotes around the array and variable references, but not around the wildcards; this means the shell will expand the wildcards (as you want) but not mess with the variable's contents.

Comment: Thanks for all the information. That's very helpful. And thanks for the more general remarks!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
array=( 37 132 253 642 242 42 );

for d in ${array[@]}; do
    INPUT_FILE1="prmrp_*_"$d"_S*_L00?_R1_001.fastq.gz";
    echo ${INPUT_FILE1}
done
```